# Eclipse doesn't know "Desktop"

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

## Problem

Weird thing:
My Eclipse (and also the one of my colleague) does not know "Desktop".
What I mean: I type "Desk" in my Java code and try to autocomplete but Eclipse does not suggest "Desktop". So it seems, like there is no "Desktop"-Class.
But the java.awt.Desktop class is still available, it just seems to be "secret"/hidden.
**Any explanation, why Eclipse hides "Desktop" from us?**
I use Java 8 in my project. Eclipse itself starts with Java 11 or 13. (how can I check?) 

This code is an example and working, so the java.awt.Desktop itself is there, only "hidden" in Eclipse:

```
package mystuff;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class PDFStuff {
    public static final String dummyPDF = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String FILE_URL = dummyPDF;
        String FILE_NAME = "dummy.pdf";
        
        InputStream in = new URL(FILE_URL).openStream();
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get(FILE_NAME), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(Paths.get(FILE_NAME).toFile());
    }
}
```

## Solution

There was a bug in eclipse and after an update it is working well again! Thanks @greg-449!

PS: I had another bug, so first I could not update Eclipse.
Problem was, that Eclipse could not remove eclipse.exe during the update process. 
This is how I fixed it:

- Run eclipse
- Rename eclipse.exe to eclipse.exe.backup
- Run updates
- Updates executed successfully
- Remove eclipse.exe.backup

Comment: The java.awt.* classes are filtered out, see the duplicate for how to change this. This is fixed in the current 2021-12 release.

Comment: There was a bug in eclipse and after an update it is working well again! Thanks @greg-449!  
I have updated my question with this solution.